Docusign: dateSigned without the time part
Can I add the DateSigned tab but remove the time part of it?
I tried the FormulaTab but couldn't find a function like split or substr.

The format of the DateSigned tabs comes from the eSignature settings in your account. If you want to display the date without the time, you would set the current time format to "None." You can see this blog post for more details.


Thank you, Paige!
Does this only affect DateSigned, or could other fields/variables be impacted?
I’m unsure if changing [Current Time Format] affects other data.
I know DateSigned Tab isn’t used in my company's document generation - so I'm happy to introduce it. But it’s definitely used in DocuSign’s last page [certificate of signature] - will the certificate's DateSigned lack the timepart?

All in all, if I change CTF - will it only affect DateSignedTab look? Will it also affect the certificate of signature? Will it affect other places?
